# group by and order by making query very slow in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by, query-optimization

This query executes quickly:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE users.id, users.name
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN user_statistics ON users.id = user_statistics.user_id
WHERE users.is_deleted = 0
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.updated_at
LIMIT 50
```

This one slowly:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE users.id, users.name, MAX(user_statistics.access_time) AS user_access_time
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN user_statistics ON users.id = user_statistics.user_id
WHERE users.is_deleted = 0
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY user_access_time
LIMIT 50
```

Here's the explain output for the slow query:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE
        table: users
         type: ref possible_keys: fk_users_is_deleted
          key: fk_users_is_deleted
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 107696
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1   select_type: SIMPLE
        table: user_statistics
         type: ref possible_keys: fk_user_statistics_user_id
          key: fk_user_statistics_user_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: users.id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
```

I am using `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` on different tables. How can I optimize the above slow query?

Comment: To make SQL queries more easily readable, consider putting SQL keywords in upper case.

Comment: How many users are there?  I don't readily see any way around the final file sort to sort by access time, so if the bulk of the time is for this sort, then this might be a problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff users - 195479

Comment: How slow is "slow"?  The query will have to sort 195k records; this might take a few seconds.  It shouldn't take minutes.

Comment: fast query takes 1sec and slow query takes 40sec.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following.  First, rewrite the query as:

```
select u.id, u.name,
       (select max(us.access_time) from user_statistics us where u.id = us.user_id
       ) as user_access_time
from users u
where u.is_deleted = 0
order by user_access_time
limit 50;
```

Create the following indexes:

```
user_statistics(user_id, access_time);
user(is_deleted);
```

This should improve performance.

NOTE:  I don't like replacing `group by` with nested subqueries but sometimes they perform faster.  If only the SQL Engine could do this optimization.

Comment: I cannot remove group by from the query because I have one more left join attached with this query.

Comment: @krunalshah . . . I can't speak to a mysterious query that was not part of the original question.  Does this approach work better than the one in the original posting?

Comment: No this is not helping me... Sorry for not posting original query.